# Change values of duplicating objects in JAVA

Tags: java

I know this question has been asked a lot but I can't figure out what the problem is in my code.

```
DateTry date1 = new DateTry("January", 3, 2004);
DateTry date2 = new DateTry(date1);
date1.setMonth("July");
System.out.println(date1.getDate());
System.out.println(date2.getDate());

public class DateTry {

    public String month;
    public int day, year;

    public DateTry(String month, int day, int year) {
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public DateTry (DateTry test) {
        this.month = test.month;
        this.day = test.day;
        this.year = test.year;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return this.month + ", " + this.day + ", " + this.year;
    }
}
```

Why does the first line outputs: "July, 3, 2004"
and the second line: "January, 3, 2004" ? I want them both to output "July, 3, 2004"

I think I have to change these lines:

```
this.month = test.month;
this.day = test.day;
this.year = test.year;
```

I saw a few answers which look like this, but did not work for me:

```
this.month = new DateTry(test.month); etc...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the first line outputs: "July, 3, 2004" and the second line: "January, 3, 2004" ? I want them both to output "July, 3, 2004"

Because `date1` and `date2` refer to two different objects. You modify the state of date1:

```
date1.setMonth("July");
```

but you didn't modify the state of date2.

Imagine you have two sheets of paper. You write the same text "hello world" on both of them. Then you erase Hello and replace it by Goodbye on the first sheet of paper. What do yo read on the second one? "Hello world", right? Same here.

> I want them both to output "July, 3, 2004"

Then also modify the state of date2:

```
date2.setMonth("July");
```

If you want these two variables to refer to the same object, then create a single object, and two variables referring to this unique object:

```
DateTry date1 = new DateTry("January", 3, 2004);
DateTry date2 = date1;
```

Comment: I want to create two objects and use the same data. That's why I need a copy constructor right?

Comment: A copy consructor, by definition, creates a **copy**. If you make a copy of a document, and then modify the original, the copy is unaffected. That's the whole point of making a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting Month only for date1, you have to set it for date2 too.
Other solution is to create date2 instance after setting date1 to July.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class for String to represent a month and the delegate the change of month to it:

```
DateTry date1 = new DateTry(new Month("January"), 3, 2004);
DateTry date2 = new DateTry(date1);
date1.setMonth("July");
System.out.println(date1.getDate());
System.out.println(date2.getDate());

public class Month {
    private String month;

    public Month(String month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public String getMonth() {
        return this.month;
    }

    public void setMonth(String month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
}

public class DateTry {

    public Month month;
    public int day, year;

    public DateTry(Month month, int day, int year) {
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public DateTry (DateTry test) {
        this.month = test.month;
        this.day = test.day;
        this.year = test.year;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return this.month.getMonth() + ", " + this.day + ", " + this.year;
    }

    public void setMonth(String month) {
        this.month.setMonth(month);
    }
}
```